# Using `scandir` with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, list, subdirectory, scandir

I am looking to quickly build a list of all folders and subfolders within a directory, *without iterating through the files in each subfolder*. This last point is why I'm not using `os.walk`. To do this, I followed an example that suggested using `scandir`:

```
import scandir
ds = scandir.scandir(datafolder)
```

This produces a `scandir.ScandirIterator object`.  How do I look at this object, or view this as a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're back to square one, my friend!  To view the "data" in an iterator object, you must iterate.  I imagine something like this will work, or at least set you on the right path (pun intended).

```
import scandir
ds = scandir.scandir(datafolder)    
print [x for x in ds]
```

Comment: This directly answers my question, thank you! I hoped `scandir` would give me the subfolders in `datafolder`, but I was hoping to get *all* subdirectories. How could I go about doing that?

Comment: @AaronJPung Somewhat ironically, `scandir.walk`.  `scandir.walk` and `os.walk` appear to functionally very similar, however the `scandir` module claims to be faster so there probably is some advantage to using it over `os.walk`